# getting compiled war file of project on EC2 Jenkins

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

My team is using JavaEE and Angular 4, and AWS EC2 server, which has Jenkins on it, and configured to, upon successful merge to `master`, build the content and generate Slack notification with the status of the build. However, when I, the guy responsible for managing that, goes into the EC2 server to check for the code, I cannot find the WAR file that Jenkins is supposed to build, in `.jenkins` or anywhere else. How do I get Jenkins to build to a .war file, that I can access to start our RESTful API service?

After fixing a misspell in the `pom.xml`, it looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zenith</groupId>
    <artifactId>SHOULDi-back</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SHOULDi-back</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/jaxrs-ri -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>






        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SHOULDi-back</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: check it in your jenkins workspace folder

Comment: Without seeing your pom file / log files etc. it's hard to guess what the problem is...Have you defined the packaging `war` ?

Comment: I type `find ~/.jenkins/workspace -name *war*` and it returns nothing.

Comment: This was setup as a freestyle project, but I see no options to do with Maven.  I created Maven project (as the trainer told me to do), but copied over that project's `config.xml` file into this project's `config.xml`, restarted Jenkins, and don't see all the Maven options

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Jenkins installation, the .war may live in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace, or a different directory. Try `find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace -name *war*` instead.

To find the Jenkins home directory if not the above, log in to the server and run `sudo su - jenkins && pwd`; if this fails, edit /etc/passwd and change the jenkins' user to use /bin/bash instead of /bin/false and try again.

Comment: Is there any thing that I need to do with the Maven integration plugin to get this to work? My team is using Maven to develop the app on their machines.

Comment: Also, this didn't work, and that was after I changed that `/etc/passwd`, shutting down the Jenkins, and re-running.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be little to do with my `pom.xml` file, which had this troublesome dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

, which I had to scrap to get the build to work and the .war file to generate. Also, I had to invoke top-level Maven target as build step. In there, I specified the path to my `pom.xml`. After doing that, build was successful and .war file was generated. As to whether or not that .war file actually works, well, that is another topic.